# How to access to a class of a tab?

Tags: android, class, tabactivity

I use a TabActivity, and I have a menu (on the title bar).
I want that when I click on a menu button, I instantiate this class in one of my tabs.

So, my tab :

```
public class Tab1 extends ListActivity {
...
   class Chargement extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
         //traitement
      }
   }
}
```

In my TabActivity, I have tried to do that :

```
Tab1 t = new Tab1();
a.new Chargement().execute();
```

But it doesn't work.

Thank's for you help.

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work"

Comment: On the phone : the application has stopped. And in the log cat : 03-16 09:27:52.516: E/AndroidRuntime(11781): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @user2021346 post complete statck trace and also complete code

Answer (score 0):

```
Tab1 t = new Tab1(); // wrong
```

**Don't instantiate Activities, they can not be instantiated.**, don't create Object for Activity. Android will take care of that. If you create such type your life cycle method won't execute.

Edit:

To get the current tab use this

tabhost= getTabHost(); // get the tabhost

```
tabhost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {         

        Log.i("***Selected Tab", "Im currently in tab with index::" + mytabs.getCurrentTab());
    }       
});
```

Comment: So, how I can access to a class present in a tab from the tab host?

Comment: Check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html, you can use getCurrentTab()

Comment: Ok but how i can instanciate a class present in my tab?

Comment: @user2021346 first of all tell me what are you trying to achieve..?

Comment: Because in my tab, I have a class "Chargement" and I want to instantiate it

Comment: I have tried this :

    Tab1 myActivity = new Tab1 ();
    Tab1 .Chargement asyncTask = myActivity.new Chargement();
    asyncTask.execute();

But it doesn't work.

Comment: It is your inner class you can call it directly with out object of that class like this  "new Chargement().execute() "

Comment: I can't access to the class "Chargement" because "Chargement" is in the class Tab1...